# JavaScript: Can I disable a particular option in a select menu based on a checked radio button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am new to Javascript and I am trying to create a form that will take bookings for a basketball tournament.

I have a radio button list and a drop down menu. The radio buttons allow the user to choose the team they want to play for and the drop down menu lets the user choose which day to play.

However, not all teams can play every day.

For example;
I'm trying to set up the form so that if the user selects that they want to play in Team A (via radio button with `name='team'`), since Team A plays every day except Sundays, only Sunday is disabled from the drop down menu.

So if the user selects Team A on the radio buttons, then in the select menu, Sunday is disabled from choice.

I'm really not quite sure where to begin.
Thanks!

EDIT: I know there are similar questions but I wasn't able to find one that involved a single value in a select group being changed based on whether or not a radio button has been checked. Since they are different form elements I don't know how to call on each specific one in the script.

EDIT 2 (CODE):

```
var gameTime = function () 
        {  
           if ($('input:radio[name="team"]').val == 'Team A')
           {
              $("option[value='Sunday']").prop("disabled", true);
           }
        };
```

That's what I had. Didn't seem to be working

Comment: Yes you can disable a particular option. Read [How do i enable/disable options in Select Box using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953589/how-do-i-enable-disable-options-in-select-box-using-jquery) might help you. Without seeing your code we can't help you.

Comment: why disabling? just dont display the option in select menu.. you can use onclick function.. post your code until now..

Comment: No one will give you a full solution without you showing some effort. Try it yourself and show what you did and where exactly you had problems.

Answer (score 1):

**Without seeing your code here is a very simple solution**

```
 $('input').click(function() {
if($('#team_A').is(':checked')) 
{
    alert("checked");
      $(".sunday").attr('disabled','true');
}
else if($('#team_B').is(':checked'))
{
      $(".sunday").removeAttr('disabled');
}
});
```

Is that What you want ??

[New Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/06s765jx/3/)

Comment: Possibly. I assume '#radio_button' and '#sunday_option' is the ID of the radio button and selection?

Comment: I did try but unfortunately it did not work. Have a look if you don't mind: http://jsfiddle.net/06s765jx/

Comment: take a look at my fiddle I have updated it for you...
Its all matter of how you manage your id's and classes for the elements .... This solution can be made even more perfect if you use functions which take dynamic id value and take certain action on it

Comment: In your solution, Sunday gets disabled for both radio buttons. I'm trying to only get it to be disabled for one (Team A).

Comment: oohh my God that was just to give you an idea .. here I have updated it again for you .. see my answer

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your team schedules are saved, so I just made something up. Basically when you choose a team, an array is referenced to see which days are available for that team, then the appropriate options in the menu are disabled.

HTML:

```
<p>Choose a team:</p>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="team" id="team-a" value="0" />
    <label for="team-a">Total Ballers</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="team" id="team-b" value="1" />
    <label for="team-b">Party People</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="team" id="team-c" value="2" />
    <label for="team-c">Weekend Warriors</label>
</div>
<p>Choose a day:</p>
<select>
    <option>-- Choose a day --</option>
    <option>Monday</option>
    <option>Tuesday</option>
    <option>Wednesday</option>
    <option>Thurday</option>
    <option>Friday</option>
    <option>Saturday</option>
    <option>Sunday</option>
</select>
```

JS (jQuery):

```
//schedules are saved in a 2D array, the seven numbers correspond to Monday through Sunday
//1 = available, 0 = not available
//first set for team A, second for team B, third for team C
var schedules = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [1,1,1,1,1,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,1,1]];

$('input').on('click', function() {
    //looks at the value of the clicked radio button
    var value = $(this).val();
    //grabs the corresponding array from schedules
    var schedule = schedules[value];
    //loops through each day in the menu, disable that option if the array shows a 0 for that day
    $('option:not(:first-child)').each(function(i) {
        if (!schedule[i]) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', true).css('background-color','#eee');
        } else {
            $(this).attr('disabled', false).css('background-color','white');
        }
    });
}).on('change', function() {
    $('option:first-child').attr('selected', true);
});
//last part changes the menu back to 'choose a day' when a different team is chosen
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/flowstoneknight/fb1ksex5/2/).