# Disable other options in a dropdown, if clicked on the first option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a dropdown were I can select multiple options. If I select one option in that, I need the rest of the options disabled.

For example :
In the below code, if I select the option All, I need the rest of the options disabled.

```
<select id="searchRegion" name="searchRegion" multiple="multiple">
<option> Choose Region(s) </option>
<option value="all"> All </option>
<option value="East"> East </option>
<option value="North"> North </option>
<option value="West"> West </option>
<option value="South"> South </option>
</select>
```

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9eMz.png)

Comment: Sounds like bad UI experience because once you have slected `All`, how user can change his selection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do i enable/disable options in Select Box using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953589/how-do-i-enable-disable-options-in-select-box-using-jquery)

Comment: Than what is the need of multiselect , you can use normal select dropdown. why this complexity ?

Comment: But why? Remove multiple and add size="6" and use optgroup. Check my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0yxe1rdp/

Comment: Use this FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/gf2rsLwz/. More than what you are asking for(BAD UI experience), this is what you really need. http://jsfiddle.net/gf2rsLwz/

Comment: I agree with @A.Wolff, you're better off using checkboxes.

Comment: @MarsOne this how you can do it http://jsfiddle.net/gf2rsLwz/1/ to enable it user has to ctrl +click the all enable the others and select actual values. by the by most of the users dont aware the ctrl functionalty this is definitely a bad UI

Comment: @OnurTOPAL, With all due respect, i did not understand what you are trying to say

Comment: @A. Wolff I have more options in my code. This is for a search box. If i have an option to select all the regions, it would be easy. and if my selection regions are just North and West, I can deselect the all button and select only those two options. Just like how we filter element in an Excel sheet

Comment: @user4269552 That should not be the purpose of SELECT element, use checkboxes instead with a check/uncheck all logic

Comment: See this for how you **should** be doing it: http://jsfiddle.net/7rtjjxn4/

Comment: basically, in first jsfiddle version, it was impossible to re enable the select box. the new one it is possible but it is still pain in the neck to handle with ctrl+click. Just a side note nothing serious.

Comment: @A. Wolff if we give multiple="multiple" in the <select> tag, it enables a checkbox for every element. so either u can select All, or multiple options

Comment: @Jamie Barker Thanks, That code helped. but I need to disable the rest of the options, not checking all. Can you help me with that?

Comment: @user4269552 I'm aware what is the multiple attribute but again, that's not the purpose of SELECT element as most users would expect it. Now why would you need to disabled them when `all` is checked. Please read: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem

Comment: @A. Wolff can u check the image i have uploaded with the request?

Comment: @A. Wolff this is my requirement. Why should i keep other elements enabled if i have an option to choose all!

Comment: @user4269552 See there, maybe: http://jsfiddle.net/7rtjjxn4/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try

```js
var $searchRegion = $('#searchRegion').change(function() {
  var isAll = $searchRegion.find('[value="all"]').is(':selected');
  if (isAll) {
    $searchRegion.val('all');
  }
  $searchRegion.find('option').not('[value="all"]').prop('disabled', isAll);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="searchRegion" name="searchRegion" multiple="multiple">
  <option>Choose Region(s)</option>
  <option value="all">All</option>
  <option value="East">East</option>
  <option value="North">North</option>
  <option value="West">West</option>
  <option value="South">South</option>
</select>
```

Comment: How I can unselect after selecting ?

Comment: @CodingAnt there is a UI design issue like that... you can use `ctrl + click` to unselect

Answer (score 0):

See http://jsfiddle.net/xn9rg0kd/

```
$("#searchRegion").on("change", function(){
    if ($(this).val()[0] == "All"){
     $("#searchRegion option:selected").siblings().attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    }
});
```